# Why may I have no "Cloud Functions Admin" role option to grant at Google Cloud?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to connect Firebase with Flutterflow.
For this, I need to grant permissions, using a provided Flutterflow login.
One of the steps is to dry Cloud Functions Admin role, associated with this login.
Problem is, there's no such option on the page where you suppose to do it!

[image]

Fun fact, with my previous project it works fine, I can see the Cloud Functions tab with this role inside.

I've checked the list of all roles, found this specific one – it's here, enabled.
I've duplicated this role and granted the duplicate instead of "Cloud Functions Admin", but still Flutterflow says there's no permission.

Comment: Is the Cloud Functions API already enabled for this project?

Comment: On which resource are you trying to grant this role? A project?

Comment: I've checked the settings, and suddenly Cloud Functions API was turned off (is it be disabled by default for the new projects?..). Thank you @nanofarad for guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Functions API had to be enabled first (as confirmed in comments). It's off by default for new projects; generally each project must enable the APIs it wishes to use.